# Numpy python find minimum value of each column and subtract this value from each column

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone help with a snippet of code using numpy and python?

Given an numpy array such as

```
a = array([[1,11], [3,9], [5,7]]
```

I want to find the minimun value of each column, so 1 and 7 and then subtract this value from the respective columns,

```
a = array([[0,4], [2,2], [4,0]]
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
>>> a - a.min(axis=0)
array([[0, 4],
       [2, 2],
       [4, 0]])
```

Where `axis=0` refers to columns.